# How to include file bytes into the POST request body in Jmeter? (What encoding to use)

Tags: rest, jmeter

I have to perform POST requests from Jmeter. I use default HTTPRequest sampler, where I specify the JSON structure that is understandable by the testing app. One part of this JSON has to contain binary data from a pdf file.

For reading the file I use BeanShellSampler in the setUp thread group:

```
File file = new File(bsh.args[0]);

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] array = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    log.info("String is read.");
    fis.read(array);
    vars.put("fileEntity", new String(array, "cp1252"));
} catch (e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

The problem is that when I look at the request with Fiddler, I see that difference, how the binary object is represented there in comparison with Postman's requests:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpu07.png)
[Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5VJ6.png)

I think that there is something wrong with the encoding when I create a String object in the BeanShellSampler. What encoding is correct?

I tried to use RawDataSource plugin but it doesn't help for two reasons:

1. It fails to read my file, saying "Error reading next chunk"
2. It uses the same approach that I do to read the file, but uses UTF8 encoding. I tried this encoding also, but without any success.

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that your `fis.read(array);` function relies on default value of the [file.encoding system property](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) which may or may not be `cp1252`.

I would recommend introducing an [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#:%7E:text=An%20InputStreamReader%20is%20a%20bridge,characters%20using%20a%20specified%20charset%20.) and explicitly specify the encoding there like:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,"cp1252");
```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because [Groovy performs much better comparing to Beanshell.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: According to my latest investigations, a PDF file is just couldn't be represented as a String variable, isn't it?